# 2.4A micro USB adapter/cable with a 1.8A Micro USB connector

Tags: usb

You can find many many USB charger/cables specified a 2.4A current capacity. But I can't find the micro USB connectors rated 2.4A on the market, the maximum is only 1.8A. So, it's safe to use a fast charging adapter labeled 2.4A with a connector labored 1.8A? Or there exist 2.4A connector indeed?

Comment: I don't think you looked very hard. I see several receptacles with 2.8A or 3A ratings on the power pins.

Comment: Really? I searched on TE and Molex, the maximum is 1.8A for Micro AB connector. I'm not here to ask others finding products for me :). But please make sure.

Comment: Try doing a parametric search on Digikey or Mouser. You may find other suppliers. ;-)